# Unable to reach ConsentController

Tags: identityserver4, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an Angular 6 app accessible at https://localhost:44391, that communicates with another server for authentication and authorization on at https://localhost:44380

I am able to establish communication between the client app and the authentication server. However after successfully authenticating the user instead of redirecting to the consent page, it goes back to the server login page.

I am using VS 2017, asp.net core 2.1 with IdentityServer4

The following is my startup class for the authentication server

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        _environment = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var stsConfig = Configuration.GetSection("stsConfig");
        var userDbConnString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        var useLocalCertStore = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["UseLocalCertStore"]);
        var certificateThumbprint = Configuration["CertificateThumbprint"];
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(UserDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;


        X509Certificate2 cert;

        if (_environment.IsProduction())
        {
            if (useLocalCertStore)
            {
                using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
                {
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                    var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprint, false);
                    cert = certs[0];
                    store.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Azure deployment, will be used if deployed to Azure
                var vaultConfigSection = Configuration.GetSection("Vault");
                var keyVaultService = new KeyVaultCertificateService(vaultConfigSection["Url"], vaultConfigSection["ClientId"], vaultConfigSection["ClientSecret"]);
                cert = keyVaultService.GetCertificateFromKeyVault(vaultConfigSection["CertificateName"]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "localhost.pfx"), "##Rojutet11");
        }

        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

        services.Configure<StsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig"));
        services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

        services.AddSingleton<LocService>();
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        //services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthentication(
            //o => {
            //    o.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //}
        );

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, UserRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("de-CH"),
                        new CultureInfo("fr-CH"),
                        new CultureInfo("it-CH")
                    };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                var providerQuery = new LocalizationQueryProvider
                {
                    QueryParameterName = "ui_locales"
                };

                // Cookie is required for the logout, query parameters at not supported with the endsession endpoint
                // Only works in the same domain
                var providerCookie = new LocalizationCookieProvider
                {
                    CookieName = "defaultLocale"
                };
                // options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, providerCookie);
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, providerQuery);
            });

        //services.AddCors();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddViewLocalization()
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                {
                    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                    return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                };
            });
        //services.AddAntiforgery(
        //    options =>
        //    {
        //        options.Cookie.Name = "_af";
        //        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        //        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        //        options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        //    });

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();



        services.AddIdentityServer(
            //x=>x.IssuerUri="https://localhost:44338"
            ).AddSigningCredential(cert)
          .AddDefaultEndpoints()
          .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
          {
              options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(userDbConnString, db => db.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
          })
          .AddOperationalStore(options => {
              options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
              builder.UseSqlServer(userDbConnString, db => db.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
          }).AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(userDbConnString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("KAMAAG.Data")));

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);



        app.UseCors(builder =>
           builder
           .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44391")              
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowCredentials()
           .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseCsp(opts => opts.DefaultSources(directive => directive.Self())
            .ImageSources(directive => directive.Self()
               .CustomSources("*"))
            .ScriptSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .UnsafeInline())
            .StyleSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .UnsafeInline()));


        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

My Client configuration:

```
public class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "kamaagwebclient",
                ClientId = "kamaagwebclient",
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 330,// 330 seconds, default 60 minutes
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 30,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
               AllowRememberConsent=true,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44391",
                    "https://localhost:44391/silent-renew.html"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44391/unauthorized",
                     "https://localhost:44391"
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
                {
                    "https://localhost:44391",
                     "http://localhost:44391"
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                   "resourcescope",
                   "securefilescope",
                    "kamaagresource",
                    "securedfiles",
                    "role"
                },
                RequireConsent=true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

AccountController: Login Methods

```
 [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        if (context?.IdP != null)
        {
            // if IdP is passed, then bypass showing the login screen
            return ExternalLogin(context.IdP, returnUrl);
        }

        var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl, context);

        if (vm.EnableLocalLogin == false && vm.ExternalProviders.Count() == 1)
        {
            // only one option for logging in
            return ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First().AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl);
        }

        return View(vm);
    }



[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        var returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl;

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                Console.Write("Failed to authenticate");
            }
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(VerifyCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberLogin });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model));
    }
```

Ok, so after several days of banging my head against the wall I decided to try the webpack approach following [this tutorial](https://damienbod.com/2016/03/02/angular2-openid-connect-implicit-flow-with-identityserver4/).I switched out the entire angularclient project for the one in this tutorial, did the necessary retrofitting and my consent page showed up which has left me a little disappointed. I thought the Angular-Cli approach offered a much more smoother ride. Maybe I am just doing something REALLY REALLY DUMB somewhere as it appears I am the only one with this problem

Comment: Could you post AccountController Login method?

Comment: @ademcaglin just added the login methods.